# How to perform a ListView setSelection(0) on a CursorAdapter after a filter operation?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

1)Create a CursorAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter to render a list.

2) Now scroll down the list a bit so you are not at position 0.

3) Now execute a CursorAdapter filter that you have created.

Result:

The filter correctly updates the data and the list view is updated with the new data.

The big problem is that the list position/selection stays at your previous position (if there are enough rows in the new result).

I want to perform a setSelection(0) within my filter to always set position to 0 but don't know how to do it. Any suggestions to the obvious?

```
dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
   public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

    listView.setSelection(0);
    return newCursor;
});
```

The above doesn't work since the setSelection() is made before data is updated, cursor swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked)` or `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)` (if you are API >= 8)?

Comment: The problem is that the data change is triggered in a runQuery method of FilterQueryProvider which means I can only affect the existing data and return the new data, and not perform any post gui updates due to data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. There is no way to update the setSelection() via the filter but overriding the changeCursor method of CursorAdapter did the trick!

```
@Override
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        super.changeCursor(cursor);

        listView.setSelection(0);
    }
```